# PDF creation through pstill

Tags: php, pdf, rgb, cmyk

I am creating my pdf file through pstill command using an EPS file which look like

`D:\\a\\GPStill\pstill.exe -w 4000 -h 4000 -d 1000 -a 4  -c -c -g -t -C -M epsrgb -Y -2 -P -W -R 0 -o ".$filepath_pdf." ".$filepath, $output`

where $filepath is the path to EPS file which will be used to create my PDF.

The problem is that, generated PDF is in RGB format as its specified in the command.I want it to be in CMYK.I have tried different commands like changing epsrgb to epscmyk but its not working.

Can any1 help ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was i removed the

`-C -M -Y` portion from my command and it worked !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you only need to remove `-C` (which specifies PStill to output in RGB colorspace). The normal call to generate CMYK in PDF is

```
pstill -M default -m XimgAsCMYK -o output.pdf input1 [input2 ...]
```